# Why Riverpod's ConsumerWidget can show state changes?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I looked at Riverpod's [counter example](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/blob/master/examples/counter/lib/main.dart) and noticed it uses ConsumerWidget instead of ConsumerStatefulWidget.

If ConsumerWidget can show state changes, is there any need to use ConsumerStatefulWidget? Why Riverpod, as a state management solution, has both stateful and stateless consumer widgets? It seems there is something I haven't yet comprehend

Answer (score 5):

ConsumerStatefulWidget is here for if you want local state in your widget. Like instantiating an AnimationController

Typically providers are for shared state. But they don't deal with local state.
Hence why you still sometimes need Statefulwidgets (or flutter_hooks if that's your thing)

Comment: This is exactly what I use ConsumerStatefulWidget for, whenever I have a lot of controllers on a certain page. Otherwise just ConsumerWidget

Answer (score 2):

I'll also add that we can quickly enough replace `StatefulWidget` with `ConsumerStatefulWidget` (and `State` with `ConsumerState`) to access the `ref` variable throughout the widget. This is very useful when we have a previously written complex `StatefulWidget` widget with lots of controllers (well, just imagine!) and suddenly we need to access `ref` and use `Riverpod` to its full potential.

Then it becomes obvious and looks amazing!

**Afterword**: later on you will also find out that `ConsumerWidget` is actually a `ConsumerStatefulWidget` :)

Comment: So is the difference between them only, one for simple states and the other for the more complex states?

Comment: In layman's terms, yes.